# How to substitute index value captured from onclick and place it to Thymleaf List of objects

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

we are having one scenario, where i have the table which displays all the records and we have an action column wherein if we click on that button a bootstrap modal appears and that modal should have values autopopulated for the selected record.

Currently, there is an onclick event which will capture the id of that particular record which is kind of index for the list of student object.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"
        th:data-parameter1="${itDetail.itdetailsId}"
        onclick="openModel(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'));">
        <i class=" fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

**Javascript function**

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function openModel(i) {
        //alert(i);       // at this we are able to capture the index value of selected record
        $('#modal-1').show();
    }
</script>
```

**Popup Modal**

```
<div class="form-outline">
        <input type="text" id="formControlLg1" class="form-control form-control-lg" **th:value="${itdetails[1].name}"** />  
      // *Here the index value is hardcoded as 1 , this i need to substitute it from javascript openModel function i*
        <label class="form-label" for="formControlLg">Name</label>
</div>
```

> Is there any way to substitute the index value captured in OpenModal
> function to this form th:value="${itrdetails[1].name}

or is there any better way to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to preset value then open the model.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function openModel(i) {
      //alert(i);          // at this we are able to capture the index value of selected record
      document.getElementById("formControlLg1").value = "${itdetails[i].name}";
      $('#modal-1').show();
    }
</script>
```

Popup Model

```
<div class="form-outline">
    <input type="text" id="formControlLg1" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
    <label class="form-label" for="formControlLg">Name</label>
</div>
```

That how you should do it.

Comment: Thymeleaf only runs on the server - it cannot respond to a user-driven client-side event.